# AD-Role bases Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the Active Directory authorization working by using roles. I think so far I checked every article but I do not get it working. Lets say Group1 is the AD group name where my user is in.

What works is, when I do the check directly on the controller:
[Authorize(Roles = "Group1")]

But now I would like to put this information in the appsettings.json like this:

```
  "SecuritySettings": {
    "ADGroup": "Group1"
  }
```

call in the startup.cs following code:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ADRoleOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ADGroup"]));
});

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

and change my controller to this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ADRoleOnly")]
```

But doesn’t matter what I change, I always get a 403 Forbidden.
My environment is IIS (has windows authentication activated) and asp.net core 3 mvc – build with Visual Studio Code.

Any suggestions what I might miss? I mean, this is basically the same example as we see often on the internet.

Thanks

Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ADRoleOnly")]
```

This will look for the role with the name `ADRoleOnly`. But what you did is create a policy named `ADRoleOnly`:

```
options.AddPolicy("ADRoleOnly", policy =>
    policy.RequireRole(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ADGroup"]));
```

So in order to check for that *policy*, you will need to change how you use the `[Authorize]` attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ADRoleOnly")]
```

Or since the policy name is the default, you can also just write this:

```
[Authorize("ADRoleOnly")]
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! I think I looked into this issue for 2-3 hours. Thanks a lot! I did not see it.